# Fail to be a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension 3. Let$\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ be a basis for $V$. Let $p_1, p_2,p_3$ be any three vectors in $V$.

Show that there are at most three distinct values of $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ such that$\{v_1+\lambda p_1, v_2+\lambda p_2, v_3+\lambda p_3\}$ fails to be a basis for $V$.

Could anyone enlighten me how to start off this proof?

Comment: A $\Bbb C^{3 \times 3}$ matrix can only have at most 3 eigenvalues.

Comment: @DHMO Sir, could you provide a bit more sketch about how to proceed?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\lambda$ will never be $0$. Let $k = \dfrac 1 \lambda$.

The statement to be proved is equivalent to:

> There are at most three distinct values of $k \in \Bbb C$ such that $\{kv_1 + p_1, kv_2 + p_2, kv_3 + p_3\}$ fails to be a basis for $V$.

Let:

- $p_1 = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3$
- $p_2 = b_1v_1 + b_2v_2 + b_3v_3$
- $p_3 = c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + c_3v_3$

The statement to be proved is equivalent to:

> There are at most three distinct values of $k \in \Bbb C$ such that $\{(k+a_1)v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3, b_1v_1 + (k+b_2)v_2 + b_3v_3, c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + (k+c_3)v_3\}$ fails to be a basis for $V$.

Further transform it to:

> There are at most three distinct values of $k \in \Bbb C$ such that $\det\left(\begin{matrix}k+a_1&a_2&a_3 \\ b_1&k+b_2&b_3 \\ c_1&c_2&k+c_3\end{matrix}\right) = 0$.

Which is essentially the same as asking for the number of eigenvalues of $\left(\begin{matrix}a_1&a_2&a_3\\b_1&b_2&b_3\\c_1&c_2&c_3\end{matrix}\right)$.

It follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, seeing that the characteristic polynomial is of degree $3$.